# Working for competitor company competitor in same building where I was fired 8 months ago

Tags: employment

I worked at supplier A until 8 months ago who is a direct competitor with supplier B at a large manufacturer C facility. I was let go from A because I messed up my job and wasn’t great and serious.

8 months later I’m offered a position at Supplier B at the same manufacturer C facility. Manufacturer C gives contracts to many suppliers like B and A.

Will my old supplier A try to get me fired because I am working for a competitor B now? Or will they tell C to tell B to fire me? This role pays much more than I currently get and I want to seriously try to do it and do my best, but am worried if the old supplier I used to work for will have an issue since we are working in the same floor at C but for a different company.

Comment: We can't tell you what A will do. They *might* do any of those things. They might not. It may depend whether you were professional in your exit from A or not. Your best bet is to work to the best of your ability at B and not do anything which might draw negative attention to you.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, I have no beef with anyone there. I was let go because I wasnt doing my role properly, but I got along with everyone very well. This role is related but slightly more my forte, and I think I can do well. I just dont want to leave my job for this position and then get fired because of my old company. I guess its just a risk thing

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, Well I am not to sure to be honest.. I just thought because I was fired for not doing my job too well they would tell company C now that I would be back (they would definitely see me as suppliers are on the same floor)... am i worrying too much?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere thanks I will likely be seeing my old colleagues daily but good to know that they wont be out for me.

Comment: If they think you're terrible, wouldn't they want you working for B making them terrible?

Comment: @JoelEtherton thats a good point. I was mainly worried about whether my old company A told C that I was let go because I wasnt good at the job. Now that I will be working again at C but for B.

Comment: @bob , nobody involved will even care or remember.  Enjoy your new job.

Comment: @bob, if they're competitors, and if A really does think you a bad worker, then your ex employer A will probably want you to remain with B, and thus impair B's competitiveness. The only exception would be if you'd done something really serious and outrageous, where A's grudge against you would rate higher than the threat of B bankrupting him through competition.

Comment: @Steve, no not at all I am friendly with everyone there, i was told i was a nice guy but I just wasn't doing the job right.

Comment: @bob, I think it unlikely that anything would be mentioned then, particularly if your failings were very subjective ("his work and leisurely atttiude could have been better" vs "his childish horseplay meant a million pound machine had to be overhauled, costing 100k"). Even if something was mentioned, your new employer, once you are inside the tent, is likely to judge you for himself, because opinions can differ. And frankly, when competing employers of an industry do get together, they usually have bigger things on their mind that gossiping about mildly lazy or underperforming ex-employees.

Comment: I'm not at all into laws, but I don't feel it would be ethical or even legal for A to push B to fire you. If that would happen, I would get in touch with a lawyer.

Comment: Also, if you're such a bad employee from A's perspective, they should be glad a competitor hires you...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one can say for sure what anyone at A, B, or C might do, so any answers you collect here will be guesses. Good guesses, even qualified, but guesses withal.

I guess that your past will not follow you because you are just not that high on anybody's list of things to pay attention to. Nothing will threaten your job *unless* supplier B *independently* comes to the same conclusion as supplier A, to wit, you are neither great nor serious. Then perhaps people will get to talking, and piece your history together.

Your best strategy for long-term employment is to be great and get serious. If you do well at supplier B, manufacturer C will neither notice nor care what happened at supplier A.

Comment: yes, and it would be very unprofessional for A to bad mouth you to B or for B to listen to them.

Comment: @Kilisi: Agree, although OP bob is worried about not so much what supplier A might tell supplier B, but what supplier A might tell manufacturer C, who is a client of both A and B.

Comment: Same thing, just comes across as a disgruntled employer and is totally unprofessional